# ajax call returning timeout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Suppose I have some `ajax` call from some `message.js`, hitting the following action

```
def create
    attributes = params.require(:message).permit(:content)
    @message = Message.create(attributes)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'messages/_create.js.erb' }
    end
end
```

in `_create.js.erb`, I have the following

```
$('.chat-messages').append('<%= escape_javascript(render("messages/create")) %>')
```

The message is indeed created but I have a `timeout` response... For debugging I put in this file `console.log('<%= @message.content %>')`, but this throws `syntax error {}` in my console. How is it possible ?

Comment: Try with `escape_javascript`: `console.log('<%= escape_javascript @message.content %>')`.

Comment: Also, why do you have a partial `_create.js.erb` and not just `create.js.erb` in which case you wouldn't need to specify the template in your `respond_to` block?

Comment: that's what I tried, same error message. Btw, can it come from the fact that I don't handle the response from the ajax call `$.ajax({
            url: "/message/create",
            type: "POST",
            data: {message: {content: val}},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }, timeout: 3000,
            
        });`

Comment: @vee, sorry I didn't know about that

Comment: The `dataType` option in your `ajax` call is the type you expect back from the server.  You are responding with `format.js`.  I would change the ajax call to `dataType: "script"` unless you want the output to be in json format, in which case you would need to add another line in your respond block for `format.json`.

Comment: @vee it worked in fact for `console.log('<%= escape_javascript @message.content %>')` but when I put `$('.chat-messages').append('<%= escape_javascript(render("messages/create")) %>')`, I get a timeout response

Comment: @vee What is weird is that with respect to the timeout error, I have this message `Rendered messages/_create.js.erb`, but I expect `render("messages/create")` to render `messages/_create.html.erb`. What is happening ?